# Add "ALL" option to the list box and change it dynamically based on the selection in the drop down list

Tags: asp.net

I have a drop down list with names of countries and a list box with different types of season like summer, winter, etc., and both of them gets updated from a table in my database in the page_load event.

During the Page_Load event, my DropDownList and ListBox get updated with all the available countries and seasons present in the table in the database.

My ListBox changes dynamically after the country is selected in my DropDownList.

For example, if I choose USA, then season would change dynamically like fall, winter, summer. Right now it works perfectly.

The only thing I want is to add an "ALL" option at the top of my ListBox if a country is selected which has all the seasons.

For example, if I choose country "X" in my DropDownList and it has all the weathers present in my database, the ListBox would have an "ALL" option at the top. Basically the "ALL" option would pop up only when all the seasons during the Page_Load event matches the seasons after a country is selected.

What I have tried:

I tried to get the total count of the list box after my page_loaded for the first time like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        int countListBox = lb.Items.Count;  
    }

}

protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                           
    if (lb.Items.Count == countListBox)
    {
        lb.Items.Insert(0, "All");
    }
}
```

Comment: There is code missing that would help answer. You say, "For example, if I choose USA, then season would change dynamically like fall, winter, summer. Right now it works perfectly." Wherever the code is that updates the listbox is probably where you want to count the items and add the new item.

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea but I'm not sure if it's what you're asking exactly.

Try adding your variable outside of the Page_Load method, so it's accessible from all methods.

```
private int _countListBox;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        // make sure the listbox is populated first.
        _countListBox = lb.Items.Count;  
    }    
}
```

Then

```
protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                           
    if (lb.Items.Count == _countListBox)
    {
        lb.Items.Insert(0, "All");
    }
}
```

Comment: I figured it out. Everything you did was alright. The only thing that needs to be changed is the variable needs to be static.